# How to create a Battleship Warship game algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, logic

I'm having trouble randomizing and adding a 2x2 ship into the game board. I need it to look like the following:

[image]

currently I can only seem to get a 1x1 ship and don't quite understand the logic for adding the 2x2 and randomizing it so that they're all connected.

also when the user inputs a '2' at the main menu I need to show the solution, meaning where the ships are. Which I also could use some help on.

Not nearly finished but please be critical when it comes to judging my code, everything helps!

Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Battleship 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int [][] board = new int [5][5];
        int [][] ship = new int [4][2];
        int [] shot = new int[2];
        boolean done = false;

        resetboard(board);
        while(!done)
        {   
            displayBoard(board);
            displayMenu();
            for(int ships=0 ; ships < 4 ; ships++)
            {
                ship[ships][0]=(int) Math.random() * 5 + 1;
                ship[ships][1]=(int) Math.random() * 5 + 1;
            }
            int choice = getMenuInput(input);       
            if(choice == 1)
            {   
                getRow(shot);
                getColumn(shot);
                if(fireShot(shot,ship) == true)
                {
                    board[shot[0]][shot[1]]= 1;

                }
                else
                {
                    board[shot[0]][shot[1]]= 0;

                }
            }
            else if(choice == 2)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
                {
                    for(int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
                    {
                        for(int z = 0; z < 3; z++)
                        {
                            if(board[x][y] == ship[z][0] && board[x][y] == ship[z][1] )
                            {
                                board[ship[z][0]][ship[z][1]]= 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                displayBoard(board);
            }
            else if (choice == 3)
            {
                done = true;
                System.out.println("Thanks For Playing");

            }
        }

    }
    public static void displayBoard(int [][] board)
    {
        System.out.println("  A B C D E");
        for(int r =0; r < 5; r++)
        { 
            System.out.print((r + 1) + "");
            for(int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
            {
                if(board[r][c] == -1)
                {
                    System.out.print(" -");
                }
                else if(board[r][c] == 0)
                {
                    System.out.print(" X");
                }
                else if(board[r][c] == 1)
                {
                    System.out.print(" *");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }
    public static void resetboard(int[][] a)
    {
        for(int row=0 ; row < 5 ; row++ )
        {
            for(int column=0 ; column < 5 ; column++ )
            {
                a[row][column]=-1;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void displayMenu()
    {
        System.out.println("\nMenu:");
        System.out.println("1. Fire Shot");
        System.out.println("2. Show Solution");
        System.out.println("3. Quit");

    }
    public static int getMenuInput(Scanner input)
    {
        int in = 0;
        if(input.hasNextInt())
        {
            in = input.nextInt();
            if(in>0 && in<4)
            {
                in = in;            
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid Entry, Please Try Again.\n");
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Entry, Please Try Again.\n");
            input.nextInt();
        }
        return in;
    }

    public static void getRow(int [] shot)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a Row Number: ");
        shot[0] = shotValid(input);
        shot[0]--;
    }
    public static void getColumn(int [] shot)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         int numb = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter a Column Letter: ");
        String choice = input.next();
        if (choice.equals("A"))
        {
            numb = 0;
        }
        else if(choice.equals("B"))
        {
            numb = 1;
        }
        else if( choice.equals("C"))
        {
            numb = 2;
        }
        else if(choice.equals("D"))
        {
            numb = 3;
        }
        else if(choice.equals("E"))
        {
            numb = 4;  
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("2Invalid Entry, Please Try Again.\n");
            input.nextLine();
        }
        shot[1] = numb;
    }

    public static boolean fireShot(int [] shot, int [][]ship)
    {
        boolean result = false;
        for(int shipHit=0 ; shipHit<ship.length ; shipHit++)
        {
            if( shot[0]==ship[shipHit][0] && shot[1]==ship[shipHit][1])
            {
                result = true;
            }else
            {
                result = false;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static int shotValid(Scanner quantity)
    {
        int shot = 0;
        boolean done = false;
        while(!done)
        {
            if(quantity.hasNextInt())
            {
                shot = quantity.nextInt();
                if(shot>0 && shot<6)
                {   
                    shot = shot;
                    done = true;
                }
                else 
                {
                    System.out.println("1Invalid Entry, Please Try Again.\n");
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("2Invalid Entry, Please Try Again.\n");
                quantity.next();
            }
        }
        return shot;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see your picture from here but if it's like standard battleship you just have to pick a direction for the "rest of the boat" once you have picked a location for its tip. You'll have to check if every direction is elligible though, if you're too close to one side of the board you shouldn't try to expand your boat in that direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to place a single ship of size 2×2 on the board and do this:

```
for(int ships=0 ; ships < 4 ; ships++)
{
    ship[ships][0]=(int) Math.random() * 5 + 1;
    ship[ships][1]=(int) Math.random() * 5 + 1;
}
```

There are several errors here:

- The random variables will always be 1, because the `(int)` conversion affects only the result of `Math.random()`, which is a pseudo-random floating-point number between 0 and 1 exclusively. Conversion to `int` truncates this to 0. Use `(int) (Math.Random() * 5)`, which will yield a random number from 0 to 4.
- You shouldn't add 1. Internally, your game uses the zero-base indices that Java uses, which is good. ()These are known to the outside as rows 1 to 5 ande columns A to E, but you take care of that in your `getRow` and `getColumn` functions.)
- You place up to four independent ships of size 1×1. (This is *up to four*, because you might end up wit one ship in an already occupied place.)

To place a single 2×2 ship, just determine the top left corner randomply and make the other ship coordinates dependent on that:

```
int x = (Math.random() * 4);
int y = (Math.random() * 4);

ship[0][0] = x;
ship[0][1] = y;
ship[1][0] = x + 1;
ship[1][1] = y;
ship[2][0] = x;
ship[2][1] = y + 1;
ship[3][0] = x + 1;
ship[3][1] = y + 1;
```

You now have two separate data structures: The board, which is all minus ones initially, and the list of ships. Your display routine suggests that you want three different values for a cell in the board: −1 is water; 1 is an unarmed part of a ship and 0 is where a shot has been fired.

But you never set these values. You set the position of the ship before displaying, but you should probably set them straight away. You should also set the locations of shots, so that you never fire at the same cell.

You need two modes for displaying the board: The in-play mode, where the unharmed ships are displayed as water and the solution mode, which shows everything as it is. You could so this by passing a flag to the routine.

Now if you think about it, you don't really need the `ship` array. Just use the information in the board:

```
int x = (Math.random() * 4);
int y = (Math.random() * 4);

board[x][y] = 1;
board[x + 1][y] = 1;
board[x][y + 1] = 1;
board[x + 1][y + 1] = 1;
```

Keep a count of ships, initially 4. When you fire at water, mark the cell with 0. When you fire at a ship, mark the cell as 0 and decrement the count of ships. If the count of ships is zero, the player has won. Otherwise, redisplay the boatrd and shoot again.